# tomcat is throwing "deploy upload fail - no space left" while deployment of war file

Tags: tomcat6, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a war file on tomcat server via tomcat manager. but each time I am getting this error:

> FAIL - Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. No space left on device

There is plenty of space on the server. I have only tomcat server and MySQL server running on the server, nothing else.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and what is the workaround?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: please share the solution if you have found the answer.

Comment: @OnkarMusale, are you sure your issue was not that the EC2 instance really was out of space at the time your login failed, but had cleaned itself up by the time you could login later to investigate?

Comment: not sure but it was out of space at the time of my login. then after that i converted my space from small to large and still not able to connect to it via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

It might be you have a permission problem here.

You can try

```
chmod 777 /opt/apache-tomcat-X.X.XX/work/Catalina/localhost/manager
```

and maybe additional

```
chmod 777 /opt/apache-tomcat-X.X.XX/webapps/sample
```

where sample is your app directory ofc.

Comment: can't ssh into my aws ec2 instance and hence can't execute that command.

Comment: Have you been able to connect to this ec2 instance via ssh before? If you did not ssh connect earlier, please check security groups: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-ssh-troubleshooting/

Comment: tried everything but nothing works so shifted to new instance and new tomcat. but i'll award bounty to you for your efforts in some time.